# How to summarize 2 different types of value with Swift

Tags: swift, sum

I'm currently using this line of code below:

```
var month: Double { cars.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value } }
// Means: month = car.value + car.value + etc
```

But now I'm about to introduce the possibility to enter a yearly amount which is tracked with a boolean and I need to update `var month`.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
// month = if !yearly { car.value + car.value + etc }
// year = if yearly { car.value + car.value + etc }
// total = month + (year/12)

OR MAYBE

// month = car.value (if yearly { /12 }) + car.value (if yearly { /12 }) + etc
```

Do you have an idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Unless I am missing something, why can’t you just calculate your total like before into a variable and return it or it / 12 in the month getter depending on the value of your yearly boolean?

Comment: Or maybe yearly is a property on each car and determines whether value is a monthly or yearly amount? If so, you did not make that at all clear (and your first solution strongly implies yearly is not part of car). If it is, add an extension to car to return the monthlyValue. It will return value or value/12 depending on yearly. Then change your month getter to use monthlyValue in the reduce.

Comment: Actually, I have a value and a boolean as attributes and the user can fill in the value and select or not the toggle. If the toggle is off, it's a monthly value but if the toggle is on, it's a yearly value. So the value can be "month" or "year" and I know it with the toggle. So I was looking for a parameter for `reduce`.

Comment: Are you saying the yearly flag is an attribute of each car? So you just need to sum up the values of all cars but for cars with the yearly attribute set you need to divide the value by 12. Then, as I said before, you can add an extension to your car object to provide a monthlyValue property and use that in the reduce.

Comment: Yes, and it's a boolean. It can be false (by default) or true as well. Actually I could save the value "raw" or "directly divided by 12" in CoreData but I prefer to keep if raw. So I track it with a Bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property/class names in this answer might not match but should give the general idea.

The original code assumed that each car’s `value` was per month:

```
var month: Double { cars.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value } }
```

There is a new Boolean attribute of `Car` which determines whether the value should be interpreted as yearly or monthly. Adding an extension on `Car` to provide a `monthlyValue`:

```
extension Car {
    var: monthlyValue: Double { yearly ? value / 12 : value }
}
```

allows it to be used to calculate a monthly total of all cars

```
var month: Double { cars.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.monthlyValue } }
```

If `yearly` is optional then some optional chaining to default to false will need to be used:

```
extension Car {
    var: monthlyValue: Double { (yearly ?? false) ? value / 12 : value }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. But for the clarification, yearly isn't optional because it's a toggle (with a var: Bool) so it can be only true or false.